# Can I use sub-headings inside a definition list?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am making a "definition of terms" page and want to group the terms based on topic, like terms about history or geography. Is it appropriate to use sub-headings such as `<h2>` within the `<dl>`?

```html
<dl>

  <h2>Terms about history</h2>
  <dt>Term 1</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
  <dt>Term 2</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>

  <h2>Terms about geography</h2>
  <dt>Term 3</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
  <dt>Term 4</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: It's not valid HTML but a layout such that wouldn't have any adverse effects (ex. a `<tr>` without a  `<table>/<tbody>`).Semantically, I would consider it bad because there's one `<dl>` for two separate categories.  Make  two `<dl>`  so the `<h2>` aren't nested within the list.

Comment: I advice you to use https://validator.w3.org/ to be sure it's match with w3c rules, because the SEO principles you can't put heading tags every where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that’s not valid. A [`dl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) element may not contain a `h2` element as child.

You could use multiple `dl` elements:

```html
<h2>Terms about history</h2>

<dl>
  <dt>Term 1</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
  <dt>Term 2</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
</dl>

<h2>Terms about geography</h2>

<dl>
  <dt>Term 3</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
  <dt>Term 4</dt>
  <dd>definition</dd>
</dl>
```

It would also be possible to use one `dl` element with two nested `dl` elements, but I wouldn’t recommend it, because it’s needlessly complex, and you can’t use actual headings:

```html
<dl>

  <dt>Terms about history</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Term 1</dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
      <dt>Term 2</dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>

  <dt>Terms about geography</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Term 3</dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
      <dt>Term 4</dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>

</dl>
```